# Disable udev for particular module

Tags: linux, udev

Is it possible to create udev rule that will disable udev for a particular module? I do not want to stop udev daemon entirely, just to disable it for a specific driver.
I have a driver that panics kernel when the driver is insmoded while udev is enabled. When udev is disabled everything works OK.
Probably OPTIONS+="ignore_device" rule would work for me, but this option was removed from udev since release 148. Is there something similar to old ignore_device option?

Comment: Uh, so in other words, you want to tell udev to not load a specific module?

Comment: @grawity, No. I want the driver to be loaded. I want something similar to

    systemctl stop systemd-udevd
    insmod /lib/modules/some_driver.ko
    systemctl start systemd-udevd

however, without stopping udev for everything but just for a particular module.